sbt libraryDependencies error: ')' expected but string literal found
I'm new to sbt and Scala. I'm following the Getting Started guide:

Open up build.sbt and add the following line:
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-parser-combinators" % "2.1.1"

Here is what I did:
val scala3Version = "3.5.2"

lazy val root = project
  .in(file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "encrypt-files",
    version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT",
    scalaVersion := scala3Version,
    libraryDependencies += "org.scalameta" %% "munit" % "1.0.0" % Test
    libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-parser-combinators" % "2.1.1"
  )

But, then I get this compilation error:
')' expected but string literal found.
What am I doing wrong?

Notice that the settings are comma-delimited. You need a comma at the end of the previous line:
                                                                  ⌄
libraryDependencies += "org.scalameta" %% "munit" % "1.0.0" % Test,
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-parser-combinators" % "2.1.1"

By the way, you can also add multiple dependencies at one time, but it requires ++= instead of just +=:
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.scalameta" %% "munit" % "1.0.0" % Test,
    "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-parser-combinators" % "2.1.1"
)

